# request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: django-views, pre-signed-url

i want to get presigned url from aws.But i am getting error:"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."

Here is the django code i have:

Sttings.py:

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '*********'

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '**********'

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '******'

AWS_REGION_NAME = '*******'

in views.py:

```
def post(self, request, key):
    bucket_name = settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                             aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                             aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                             config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'),
                             region_name=settings.AWS_REGION_NAME
                             )
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('put_object',
                                                    Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,
                                                            'Key': key},
                                                    ExpiresIn=3600)
    except ClientError as e:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, data={"error_message": str(e)})
    else:

        return Response({
            "url": response
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to create a user and grant getobject, putobject permissions in AWS.The Documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example3.html